# CSS BOX SHADOW ISSUE

Tags: css

Hi Iam trying to create shadow to box inside another box but not getting what I want

```
<div class="box effect2">
    <div class="box effect2">
        box inside box
    <div>
<div>
```

CSS Styles

```
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}


    .effect2
    {
      position: relative;
    }
    .effect2:before, .effect2:after
    {
      z-index: -1;
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      bottom: 15px;
      left: 10px;
      width: 50%;
      top: 80%;
      max-width:300px;
      background: #777;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
      box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
      transform: rotate(-3deg);
    }
    .effect2:after
    {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
      transform: rotate(3deg);
      right: 10px;
      left: auto;
    }
```

I tried this code but not successful. Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong?
I have taken code reference from the css tricks website

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I am not getting the shadow for inner box

Comment: Your shadow is there - both are set to `z-index: -1`, so both shadows are under everything. You also don't close your `divs` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Turning my comment into an answer. Both shadows are there, you have the `z-index` set to -1, so the shadows fall under everything.

```css
.box {
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.effect2, .effect3 {
  position: relative;
}

.effect2:before,
.effect2:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.effect2:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}

.effect3:before,
.effect3:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #cc0000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #cc0000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #cc0000;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #cc0000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box effect2">
  <div class="box effect3">
    box inside box
  </div>
</div>
```

I added another class to the inside box so you can see what's happening. Also, you will have a difficult time setting this style of drop shadow to a child and parent element because of the z-indexes.

EDIT***
*Here's the solution you're looking for. I had to add another element:*

```css
.box1 {
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.box2 {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.effect1:before,
.effect1:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.effect1:after {
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}


.effect2:before,
.effect2:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.effect2:after {
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1 effect1">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="box2 effect2">my box</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9nqcx28a/8/

Comment: use this 
<div class="box effect2">
  <div class=" effect3" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid red">
    box inside box
  </div>
</div>

Comment: It's still there, it's just underneath the `effect2` div. Turn the background color to transparent on `effect2` div and you'll see.

Comment: @ManojThakur I don't understand what you're trying to show, nor why you put your styles in-line in the fiddle, plus a bunch of other classes. Your original question was about the child box not having a drop shadow, which it does, just underneath everything because of the negative z-index.

Comment: Please see this https://jsfiddle.net/9nqcx28a/5/ the inner box does't have shadow. I am trying to show the shadow of the child box inside the parent box.

Comment: Yes, I know what you're trying to do. As I've said, the inner box has DOES have a shadow, but because of `z-index: -1` the shadows (pseudo elements) appear BELOW the parent (outer box): https://jsfiddle.net/9nqcx28a/6/

Comment: you just made the parent box background to transparent,I want a backgroud and this will not work

Comment: @ManojThakur yes, I know. That's what I've been telling you. _"Also, you will have a difficult time setting this style of drop shadow to a child and parent element because of the z-indexes."_ My answer and comments show that 1) your drop shadow is there. 2) You will have a difficult time doing that type of drop shadow on the inner box because of the negative z-index.

Comment: I also tried with setting z-indexes,but nothing works

Comment: @ManojThakur Correct. Because of z-index stacking order.

Comment: @ManojThakur I updated my answer with a solution for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159598/discussion-between-disinfor-and-manoj-thakur).